# Failed to install node-libcurl for electron 5.0.10, both on mac and windows

Tags: electron, node-libcurl

I can add the `node-libcurl` to `package.json`/`yarn.lock` by typing `yarn add node-libcurl`. But when going to the second phase `electron-rebuild`, it failed all the time. I tried many node versions with nvm from `10.11.0` to `13.5.0`, all failed. I would doubt it is a `electron-rebuild problem`, but not sure. How to make it work with electron. Can someone fatcat give me a clue?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `yarn add node-libcurl` is installing the prebuilt binary for the Node.js version you are using, and not for Electron.

To use `node-libcurl` with electron the yarn command needs some extra environment variables, this is the command you should be running:

```
npm_config_build_from_source=true \
npm_config_runtime=electron \
npm_config_target=$(yarn --silent electron --version) \
npm_config_disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell \
yarn add node-libcurl
```

Comment: `npm_config_runtime=electron npm_config_target=5.0.10 npm_config_disturl=https://atom.io/download/atom-shell yarn add node-libcurl`, I wanted to use the prebuild binary and tried this several times, it didn't work. I also tried to build from source with `npm_config_build_from_source=true`, it didn't work neither.

Comment: I opened an issue for this with some detailed logs. Please check it. https://github.com/JCMais/node-libcurl/issues/206

Comment: May you please add an electron demo in the repo? I use the guidance of building from source for electron on mac, it installed successfully, but when imported from my project, it compiled failed. @JCM